# how to use the Pagination Class when some scripts in the controller are written in raw PHP

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have script to display database information without reloading the page. The script is working fine but the problem is I want to use the codeigniter's pagination class here and but since I have used some raw PHP in my controller, I don't know how to do this. 
Would you please kindly show me how to use the pagination class in my script?

Thanks in Advance :)

The scripts I have::

Inside Head

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {
     $("select[name='users']").attr("selectedIndex", 1);
     $("select[name='users']").change(function() {
     var str = $(this).val();

   if( str == "" ) {
        $("#txtHint").html("");
    }
    else {

        $.get("<?php echo base_url(); ?>test/query/"+ str, function(data) { $("#txtHint").html(data) });
    }
   }).change();
  });

</script>
```

Inside Body

```
   <form>
    <select name="users" >
                <option value="">Select a person:</option>
                <option value="11080101">Sumon</option>
                <option value="11080102">Donno</option>

            </select>
</form>
                <br />
        <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

My Controller:

```
  function query($id){



    $sql="SELECT * FROM attendancein WHERE attendeeid = '$id' ";

                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                echo "<table border='1'>
                <tr>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>In Time</th>
                <th>In Status</th>
                <th>Class Start Time</th>

                </tr>";

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                  {
                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['intime'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['instatus'] . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $row['classstarttime'] . "</td>";

                  echo "</tr>";
                  }
                echo "</table>";


                }
```

I have no model

## Edit

```
    function query($id){
             $sql="SELECT * FROM attendancein WHERE attendeeid = '$id' ";
             $result = mysql_query($sql);        

                             $this->load->library('pagination');
             $config['base_url'] = base_url().'test/srijon';
             $config['total_rows'] = mysql_num_rows($result);
             $config['per_page'] = '20';
             $config['num_links'] = 20;

            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination" align="center">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);



            $sql="SELECT * FROM attendancein WHERE attendeeid = '$id' LIMIT 20, 5";
             $result = mysql_query($sql);

                echo "<table border='1'>
                        <tr>
                        <th>date</th>
                        <th>In Time</th>
                        <th>In Status</th>
                        <th>Class Start Time</th>

                        </tr>";



                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['intime'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['instatus'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['classstarttime'] . "</td>";

                            echo "</tr>";
                        }

                        echo "</table>";

             echo "<tr><td>" . $this->pagination->create_links() . "</td></tr>";

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it is possible but you will have to add in some code.

```
function query($id){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM attendancein WHERE attendeeid = '$id' ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);        

    $items_per_page = 5;
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'test/query/'.$id.'/';
    $config['total_rows'] = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $config['per_page'] = $items_per_page;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $current_page = ($this->uri->segment(4) === FALSE ? 0 : intval($this->uri->segment(4))); 
    $offset = $items_per_page * ($current_page - 1);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM attendancein WHERE attendeeid = '$id' LIMIT '$offset', '$items_per_page'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>date</th>
    <th>In Time</th>
    <th>In Status</th>
    <th>Class Start Time</th>

    </tr>";

    echo "<tr><td>" . $this->pagination->create_links() . "</td></tr>"

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['intime'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['instatus'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['classstarttime'] . "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}
```

I haven't tested this myself but am pretty sure it will work at any rate it will give you a good idea of what you need to do to get it to work.  **Note the 5 can probably be put into a variable to make it more maintainable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, JD Guzman. I tried your script and i had to make a little change to run it(was showing an error). Please check the edited portion of my post for the code. After I make some changes in your code, it is displaying the pagination that I wanted but it is always displaying the last page as current page. And when I click to move to the previous page, an error message appears which says "Undefined variable: id" . Probably its not getting the value of "id" when moving to the next page. Would you please kindly take a look at this? Thank you very much again. :)

Comment: Ok a few things with the changes you made.  First you hard coded the LIMIT values which means that you are constantly skipping 20 records and returning 5.  I see from your config that you want 20 per page so the 5 needs to be 20.  I have made some changes to my code that should get you what you need. Again I have no reliable way to test this ATM but this should help you along.